# How do I print/echo out specific array php

Tags: php, arrays

Okay, I have searched for at while, but I really can't get this to work, and I don't know why.

```
$lump = $row['facts'];
$start_tag = '[start]';
$end_tag = '[mid]';

if(preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($start_tag).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($end_tag).'/s', $lump, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

This outputs something like:

```
Array ( [0] => Name [1] => Age [2] => City [3] => Status [4] => Children
```

How do I echo out these arrays? I mean, I have tried something like:

```
echo $matches['1'];
```

Note that the outputs will be very different, so Name, Age, City and so on will change, so I can't use something like:

```
echo $matches['Name']['1'];
```

Comment: what about var_dump?

Comment: `echo $matches[1][0];` will echo `Name`; `echo $matches[1][1];` will echo `Age`; etc

Comment: @MarkBaker - YES! That's it - Couldn't figure it out. Thank you very much!! Answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every item you do something such as:

```
$myArray = array(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
foreach($myArray as $array)
{
    foreach($array as $value)
    {
        echo $value . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Or for single items:

```
$myArray = array(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
print $myArray[0][0]; 
print $myArray[0][1];
print $myArray[0][2];
```

And this will give you your result :)

Answer (score -2):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```